# How do I display a collection of items that can't be interacted with?

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

I have a List that I want to display as a vertical list of TextBlocks. Currently I'm using a ListView, which is working OK, but I don't want the user to be able to interact with the list at all. Currently they can click on them, which gives a "pressed" animation. How can I just present it without any interactivity? I am already using SelectionMode="None" and IsItemClickEnabled="false".

Comment: How about setting the IsEnabled Property on the ListView ? than there can't be any interaction with the control anymore

Comment: Thanks @Mark, but that then changes the visual style to be dimmer too, can that be stopped?

Comment: You can override the Template of the Control and delete that Styling change on IsEnabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, you can also use the base class **ItemsControl** instead of ListView. ListView is a subclass of ItemsControl with the added ability to select items, making ItemsControl a good choice when you want a list of non-selectable items.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like IsHitTestVisible="False" works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with Gary; also ListBox is much more lightweight than ListView, so I'd suggest ListBox if you don't want to create your own ItemsControl.

Comment: ItemsControl can be directly instantiated; so there's no need to subclass and create your own. You can drop it right into the XAML as-is.